# Why is defining chunked objects (for lack of a better term) in a function valid JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I recently read [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/unit-testing-react-components-aeda9a44aae2) on unit testing React.

In it the author uses syntax like this:

```
describe('ClickCounter component', async assert => {
  const createCounter = clickCount =>
    render(<ClickCounter clicks={ clickCount } />)
  ;
  {
    const count = 3;
    const $ = createCounter(count);
    assert({
      given: 'a click count',
      should: 'render the correct number of clicks.',
      actual: parseInt($('.clicks-count').html().trim(), 10),
      expected: count
    });
  }
  {
    const count = 5;
    const $ = createCounter(count);
    assert({
      given: 'a click count',
      should: 'render the correct number of clicks.',
      actual: parseInt($('.clicks-count').html().trim(), 10),
      expected: count
    });
  }
});
```

The part that I'm confused about is the content of the callback function that has `assert` as its argument.

In it he just chains one object after another. He basically does this:

```
const myFunc = () => {
  {
    // object that confuses me, with promise (`assert`) which resolves
  }
  {
    // another object
  }
}
```

And somehow the code in these objects gets executed. I have never seen code like this in any course I watched or book I read on JavaScript. I have also never experienced such syntax used in any other library or framework. But, I tested it and the code works, the tests all run.

Notice how he also never returns anything. And even though he uses the keyword `async` he doesn't `await` anything.

Why are these chunked objects valid JavaScript? How does it work? And is there a definitive nomenclature for this? I have looked on MDN (and Google) and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is called a `compound statement`.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)